# Text Not Fitted in ASP:DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I'm Using `ASP:DropdownList(Code Behind Approach)` which has some events assosiated with it, my problem is my full text is not visible in the dropdownlist it is due to the width of dropdown list which I can't increase so how can I show the full text 
I searched this Link

http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycomboboxexamplestyle.aspx

at one place in I used Jquery ui Widget but my events are not fired because it ultimately renders textbox.

Does anyone have any solutions?

thanks in advance

CSS Class

```
.dropdown
 {
    border: #000000 1pt solid;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: verdana;
    text-align: left;
    height: 22px;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: can u post your code ? so that we can look on it ?  i suggest you to use cssclass property of the dropdownlist control

Comment: try putting     overflow:visible;     to ur dropdownlist styling.

Answer (score 2):

No need to implement any messy logic for this issue. The answer is sweet and simple. Just remove the property "Width" in the ASP:DropdownList in the .aspx page. The dropdown will expand to the width of the largest item added to it.

Also remove the width properties added to the Css class of the dropdown.

Comment: yea thats a good solution that i totaly agree with. +1 for simplicity.

Comment: the text is too large it never fit that way

Comment: @d.Siva . The solution works for me and Berker as well. Can you please post the text size you are adding. Also check that the container in which the ASP:DropdownList is added should not have a fixed size;  incase your text is too large than the container width itself.

Comment: @d.Siva . Place this code in the code behind page protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string item = string.Empty;
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("foofoo");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            item += "foo";
        }
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(item);
    } and this code in your aspx page. <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form> .I was able to add a item of width 300 characters in the dropdown and it expanded dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand ur havign problems with showing the text of ur options.

These are style classes of ur options

```
comboboxDropDownItemClass: "comboboxItem", 
comboboxDropDownItemHoverClass: "comboboxItemHover",
```

and here is ur options style sheet.

```
.comboboxItem { background:#fff; color:#000; text-transform:lowercase; 
                font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; overflow:visible; } /* here is ur text visibility */ 

.comboboxItemHover { background-color:#999; color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase;
                     padding-left:4px; overflow:visible; } /* here is ur text visibility */
```

and what u need to do just putting `overflow:visible;` there.

if still not solved than just change the width of the `comboboxItem` that should do the job.

Comment: i put overflow:visible its working in Mozilla and Chrome but not working in IE 7,8, i can not increase the width because the text is too large it never fit that way

Comment: that didnt amazed me. IE always much of a problem but ill search for it for a solution.

Comment: try also adding overflow:visible !important;

if there is an overriding for IE overflow in ur css sheet !important would make it first priority and all other stylings in same type(overflow for this situation) that has effect on ur element will be overridden with ur important! styling.
also for ie6 u can use "* html .blablablaclass { /* style here! */ } " 
also there are other ways that u can use. Like adding style on ur element with jquery.
im out of juice. inform me if it works or not.

Comment: or just came to my mind let it be like that and just add "title" to ur options that has the same text in it and u can also have ur dropdowns title changed by ur choosen option. this will allow u to see any text on ur options when ur mouse over them.

Answer (score 0):

You can mess with the font size so it "auto fits" the width of the drop down list.

To achieve that, just decrease the font size when item is selected until it fits:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown").each(function() {
        $(this).data("org_fontsize", $(this).css("font-size"));
    });


    $(".dropdown").change(function() {
        var ddl = $(this);
        var fontSize = parseInt(ddl.css("font-size"), 10);
        if (!isNaN(fontSize)) {
            var originalWidth = ddl.outerWidth();
            ddl.css("width", "auto");
            var currentWidth = ddl.outerWidth();
            if (currentWidth > originalWidth) {
                while (currentWidth > originalWidth) {
                    fontSize--;
                    if (fontSize < 2)
                        break;
                    ddl.css("font-size", fontSize + "px");
                    currentWidth = ddl.outerWidth();
                }
            }
            else {
                ddl.css("font-size", ddl.data("org_fontsize"));
            }
            ddl.css("width", originalWidth + "px");
        }
    });
});
```

This will also restore the original font size for items that don't exceed the width.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/YZWen/1/).

Comment: @d.Siva. worked fine for me just now. What you mean "not working"?

Comment: In IE 7,8 after expansion of dropdown full text is not visible

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce.. tried with IE9 compatibility view that should simulate IE8 and it still resized the text to fit the width.